# Styling a marker in LightningChart JS

Tags: lightningchart

I am adding a list of markers to my chart based of certain conditions, these conditions are varying and therefore I will need to have markers that look different:
(using the setGridStrokeXStyle function doesn't seem to have an effect. What is the correct way to accomplish this?)

```js
        Markers.map((marker) => {
        const chartMarker = chart.addChartMarkerXY()
            .setPosition({ x: new Date(marker.x) - startDate, y: marker.y });

            chartMarker
            .setResultTableVisibility(UIVisibilityModes.always)
            .setResultTable((table) => table
                .setContent([
                    ['Type']
                ])
            )
            .setGridStrokeXVisibility(UIVisibilityModes.whenDragged)
            .setGridStrokeYVisibility(UIVisibilityModes.whenDragged)
            .setTickMarkerXVisibility(UIVisibilityModes.whenDragged)
            .setTickMarkerYVisibility(UIVisibilityModes.whenDragged)
            .setDraggingMode(UIDraggingModes.notDraggable)
            .setGridStrokeXStyle(new SolidLine({ fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX("#FF69B4"), thickness: 2 }) })); //This doesn't seem to change the marker's appearance.

        console.log("style", chartMarker.getGridStrokeXStyle());
    });
```

Comment: I believe the question is missing. What are you looking for? What is your expected visual result?

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen In the code block, I indicated that setGridStrokeXStyle doesn't seem to be having an effect, and I'm not sure if that is the right way to go about it. I've updated the question hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen, As for visual results I would like the marker to take on the #FF69B4 colour, just as an example.. the end result will be to style the marker dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why in your code snippet the `setGridStrokeXStyle` is seemingly not having an effect is because the X grid stroke is not visible.

I have highlighted which element the "X grid stroke" is in the below picture with **red** to make sure:

[image]

As per why this is not visible in your example code, it is due to this method call which makes it so it is only displayed when the Chart Marker is being dragged.

```
.setGridStrokeXVisibility(UIVisibilityModes.whenDragged)
```

Furthermore, this other method call makes it so that the Chart Marker can not be dragged, which results in the X grid stroke never being visible.

```
.setDraggingMode(UIDraggingModes.notDraggable)
```

Here are some examples of styling different parts of the Chart Marker properly:

[image]